# move from ListFragment to Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to move from my Custom ListView(which is a ListFragment) to another Fragment by onClick() of a Item. I want to also pass some data which I do by

```
Fragment f = null;
f = new DescriptionFragment();// it extends Fragment
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString("title", "This is title");
args.putString("desc", "This is Description");
f.setArguments(args);
```

But Nothing happens using this code.

I tried at my level but now I think that I should use FragmentManager & FragmentTransaction. I tried to implement it by writing

```
 FragmentManager fragmentManager;
 android.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
 fragmentTransaction.remove(f);
 fragmentTransaction.commit();
 fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
 fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
 fragmentTransaction.add(containerViewId, fragment);// this line gives error & i dont know what to write here
 fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

I think my destination class is fine. It looks like this

```
public class DescriptionFragment extends Fragment {

public DescriptionFragment(){}

TextView title,desc;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.description,container,false);
    Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
    String stitle = bundle.getString("title");
    String sdesc = bundle.getString("desc");

    TextView title = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    TextView desc = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);

    title.setText(stitle);
    desc.setText(sdesc);

    return rootView;
}
}
```

Does In description.xml do I have to implement FrameLayout??

However description.xml looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp" 
     android:background="@drawable/flagc">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Small Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/ashokb" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
             android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
             />

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I hope I made my problem clear

Any help?

Comment: fragmentTransaction.add(containerViewId, fragment);// this line gives error & i dont know what to write in its parameters

Answer (score 0):

Create a Frame Layout in your activity.

Create 2 different Fragment Layouts for each fragment.

When a fragment is called use

```
transaction.replace(frameLayoutId, fragmentToReplace);
transaction.commit()
```

Here is a sample for a fragment transition that I am using in my App

```
public void changeTab(View view) {

    int id = view.getId();
    if (modelSelected) {
        FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        InfoFragment info = new InfoFragment();
        SettingsFragment settings = new SettingsFragment();
        ReportFragment reports = new ReportFragment();

        switch (id) {
        case R.id.infoTab:
            transaction.replace(R.id.loadTabFrag, info);
            break;
        case R.id.settingsTab:
            transaction.replace(R.id.loadTabFrag, settings);
            break;
        case R.id.reportsTab:
            transaction.replace(R.id.loadTabFrag, reports);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        transaction.commit();
        estheticTabHandler(id);
    } else {
        createSelectModelToast();
    }
}
```

If you want to pass data from one fragment to another you should use a Bundle. In that case you should create a fragment and set its arguments.

Example:

```
MyFragment myFrag = new MyFragment();
Bundle myBundle = new Bundle();
myBundle.putWhateverData(data); // Where whatever data is the object that you are passing
myFragment.setArguments(myBundle);
```

And them inside your `MyFragment onCreateView()` you can use:

```
Bundle args = this.getArguments();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fragmentTransaction.add(containerViewId, fragment);
```

in above line where you declare fragment object so it gives error. you remove f fragment but no any valid fragment give so it gives you error.just declare your fragment same as f fragment. thats it...

Comment: Thank u for ur reply. The error in 2nd parameter is resolved. Can u tell me about the error in first parmeter it should be like `R.id.*****`

Comment: your first parameter container and second is what you want to fill in to that container. so your first parameter is your framelayout id.and second is fragment.